# Cannot send notification on devices via token

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I am using Firebase and I want that when a user updates a value in the Firebase DB, a notification is sent to other users, so I have followed a tutorial to write functions.
So, I have stored the token values in the DB and I use them to send the massage. Anyway, when I add new data nothing happens.
Using logs I have found that the tokens are correct, and I have no error. Any idea on what is happening or what I can do to debug?

Here's the code:

```
/* eslint-disable */

const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.androidPushNotification = functions.database
    .ref("{nodo}/spese/{spesaPush}")
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
      // const nodo = context.params.nodo;
      const original = snapshot.val();

      const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database()
          .ref('/token').once('value');

      let tokensSnapshot;
      let tokens;
      tokensSnapshot = await getDeviceTokensPromise;

      console.log(tokensSnapshot.val())
      tokens = Object.keys(tokensSnapshot.val());
      
      const result = "Simple text to send";

      // Notification details.
      const payload = {
        notification: {
          title: 'New data inserted!',
          body: result, 
        }
      };
      console.log(`The tokens retrieved are: ` + tokens);
      const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
      return result;
    });
```

Comment: so the array of `tokens` is correct? seems odd to use `.keys` rather than `.values` - but then, what do I know

Comment: Exactly, the array is correct

Comment: so, the keys of that object are the tokens ... I take it the values are not

Comment: I have followed this example: https://github.com/chriso23/fcm-notifications/blob/master/functions/index.js